# Google Add Place API is not giving any response after added new location into Google places API - iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I need to add a new business place by using the google places API which is not already in google places database. For this we have used `addPlace: callback:^` I believe this method once successfully added a new business location that call backs send a response to us and Places API are reviewed and, if approved, added to the global places database.

I have used the same call back method, but can't get any response from it.

My code is below,

```
GMSPlacesClient *placesClient;

[placesClient addPlace:userAddedPlace callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"User Added Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Added place with placeID %@", place.placeID);
    NSLog(@"Added Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Added Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
}];
```

We keep the location details in this object **userAddedPlace**

Is there any issue in this code? help me out why i didn't get the response after call this method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you init placesClient  object? try GMSPlacesClient *placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];

Comment: Thanks MirMiratom, i have tried to init the placesClient object, but i got an error like the operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain error -1.)